# What users can access my AppEngine application that is protected by Identity Aware Proxy for an internal OAuth application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity, identity-aware-proxy

IAP allows you to protect apps on AppEngine by defining which principal has access using `roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor`. If I have a group in IAM called `participants` and I add external people (personal gmail accounts & contractors) to that group, will these people have access to my application?
Or do I have to submit the application for verification even though I want to limit the access to our employees and a few dozen customers taking part in a workshop?

So in other words, does IAP define "people in your organisation" as people who have a `@myorg.com` email address only or as people who are part of a group that has IAM permission?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"People in your organization" are users who have been granted permission in your Google Cloud Project or Organization. This includes **@gmail.com** accounts, which can have roles granted and can be added to groups.
For an internal application you do not need to verify the app, but you will need an [internal OAuth](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#user-type&zippy=%2Cinternal) page.
You can find more information in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart).